# How to scroll DataGrid continuously?

Tags: silverlight

I need to scroll DataGrid continuously, so it will move to next row each second (for example), and move to the first item when end is reached. Plz suggest the best way for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use a Dispatcher and each second you count up the selected index.
Something like this:

```
  private int selectedIndex;
            public int SelectedIndex
            {
                get { return selectedIndex; }
                set
                {
                    selectedIndex = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
                }
            }

            private void BuildDispatcher()
            {
                DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimerTick;
                dispatcherTimer.Start();
            }

            void DispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if((SelectedIndex + 1) > MyCollection.Count)
                {
                    SelectedIndex = 0;
                }else
                {
                    SelectedIndex++;
                }
//EDIT!
               MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;
                MyDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(MyDataGrid.SelectedItem, MyDataGrid.Columns[0]);
            }
```

**EDIT**

The selected index is set in code behind here, you can also bind it and do the ScrollIntoView stuff in the selection changed handler.

BR,

TJ

Comment: It doesn't work. Select item changes, but grid doesn't scroll.

Comment: Hi, you are right. See my edit. You need to add ScrollIntoView to get it done. MyDataGrid is the grid which holds the data. If you want to bind it, you can handle the selection changed event and then use the ScrollIntoView. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: bad solution anyway :) There is a big delay until selected item reaches end of the first page, and only then it starts scrolling.